# Consume marvel api with dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to consume a Marvel API. I'm following the steps given in the Api documentation. I have no idea how to convert what I need to MD5. I know I can use crypto package, but I don't know how to start.

Here is the api documentation= https://developer.marvel.com/documentation/authorization

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt your String data to MD5, follow these steps:

1. Add this import on top of the file:

> import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

2. Use this code to convert any String to MD5:

> String MD5 = md5.convert(utf8.encode('your string
> data')).toString().toUpperCase();

*The .toUpperCase() is optional.*